How can I use shared memory with zenoh middleware
I am trying to use rmw_zenoh as my middleware implementation. I edited the session config provided to enable shared memory. As I try to run 2 nodes (demo_nodes_cpp talker and listener) on the same device I get the following error messages:
Unable to obtain publisher GID from the attachment.
Unable to obtain sequence number from the attachment.
Unable to obtain sequence number from the attachment.
When I check network traffic using wireshark I can see the nodes still communicating via TCP. How can I use shared memory?

It's not supported yet (until 06-11-2024), but it's on rmw_zenoh roadmap. Since all shared memory APIs are ready in Zenoh, I think it will come soon.
